# Execution order of functions inside a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, function-call

Suppose to run the following code:

```
def foo():
    return 1


def bar():
    return 2

d = {'foo': foo(), 'bar': bar()}
```

In the dictionary literal, will the `foo()` call be always executed before `bar()`, or this can not be, in general, taken as granted?

Also, do the other common structures (tuples, lists, sets) behave similarly to the dictionary?

Comment: It's arbitrary. To get a certain order, use a sequence of pairs of values — i.e. `d = dict((('foo', foo), ('bar', bar()))`

Comment: @martineau: [citation needed] – dict literals are supposed to be evaluated left to right. See the duplicate and the bug that was fixed relating to it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-dict-display: “If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, they are evaluated from left to right”

Comment: Please, just assume it's unpredictable. If your code relies on order of evaluation inside an initialization, that's a confusing bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @Ry: I didn't realize they fixed that bug in Py 3.5 (or that it was even considered a bug — made sense to me given that dictionaries (used to be) unordered. Thanks for the heads-up.